# How to use md5 hashed password (get from external API) to create user in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, passwords, md5, salt, whmcs

From the WHMCS API I get these data:

- email
- password

I get the email in normal format (email@example.com). But I get the password in following format:

- 41bef39ea1086512d8b90b2a3dbc4d3e:jh#sZ (using XML)

Here, **jh#sZ** is salt and the format is **"md5(salt.pw):salt"**

Now my question is, how can I use this password in **wp_insert_user()** or in **wp_create_user()** function to insert the user in the wp database?

Comment: why would you need to do that?

Comment: I will need this to insert all whmcs registered user to the wp database, so they don't need to wp site again to comment on posts.

Comment: heres the problem wp_insert_user() accepts the array of user_pass but that has to be a plain text passwd because will salt/md5 the passwd auto, wp_create_user() creates a new user with the user,pass,email data but WP will salt/md5, so it will causes errors if you do that

Comment: Is that the plaintext password or a hashed pass?

Comment: if you have a lot of users, too many to reset their passwords you could try the [wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)

Comment: @DavidChase did you mean to directly insert data to the wp user table using wpdb?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert MD5 hash password into the database using $wpdb, after inserting user. **Existing md5 password will work**. If someone is looking for the query, here it is:

```
global $wpdb;

$user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);

$result = $wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->users,
    array( 'user_pass' => $user_pass ),
    array( 'ID' => $user_id )
);
```